Movie about an autistic person stopping doomsday
This movie is about meteor/space object hitting Earth. This is what I remember about the movie:

This movie is not very old. I think it came out perhaps around early 2000s.
There's a scene in which a woman scientist states that all the paper in the world is not enough to make calculations about the meteor/space object.
There's a scene in which an autistic man calls the leader of the scientists. He says that he already did the some sort of calculation/formula to stop the doomsday. The leader does not believe him, but the autistic man mentions some of his calculations, and then the leader believes him.

It'd be great if the title is identified. I'd like to watch it again.

no it's not, i think.

Was this a box office film or made for tv? What country?

I think it's box office. not a tv show.series.

American I think

This sounds like Quantum Apocalypse from 2010.

In the city of Parish, the Major Ben Marshall lives with his autistic brother Terry, his son Leo, his daughter Samantha and his second wife Lynne. When a comet changes its route and collides on Earth, the scientists discover that an anomaly is the cause and they bring two geniuses to join their team in the research. They find that the anomaly is a gravitational vacuum indeed and mankind is doomed to annihilation. But Terry convinces his brother Ben to drive him to Houston to save the planet.

Also, at one point, a female physicist says a formula is so complex that she doesn't even know if there's enough paper in existance for her to calculate it. Here's the trailer:



